# What does PRNDSB means?

Tags: automatic-transmission, turbocharger, 4wd

My Daihatsu Mira does not have any manual, Its an automatic car with TurboEngine and Gear with PRNDSB. What does all these means? My car is four wheel drive as I can see rear differential in it. If its a four wheel on which position of Gear I can activate the four wheel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The letters are standard:

- Park
- Reverse
- Neutral
- Drive
- Sport (or possibly Snow - thanks @Brian)
- Braking (usually for going down hills)

None of these have anything to do with 4WD or 2WD selection. If your Daihatsu is the 4WD version, it is permanently 4WD - there is no selector on that spec of car. It was a specific Japanese edition.

You have stated previously that you thought your car was a 2WD spec. I would read the [online specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daihatsu_Mira) to find out exactly which model you have.

Comment: from wikipedia "As usual four-wheel-drive versions received a different model code (L285)" Yes my car is L285S so its permanently 4WD, is it ok?

Comment: What do you mean,'is it ok'? It is how it is designed.

Comment: I've also seen the "S" used for "Snow" transmission modes before.

Comment: @Brian - in this context you may be right. It is a 4WD with a downhill braking mode, so it is definitely the type of car that could have a snow mode. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Here straight from the toyota faqs on my toyota corolla

Answer (score 0):

"S" can be used for snow and as well as steep hill/ slope. "B" is for Braking. And it is used for going down steep slope/ hill.  And both positions work irrespective of 2WD or 4WD.

Comment: Do you have a reference for what you are stating?